# Keeping the punctuation marks after using preg_split at?

Tags: php, preg-split

I'm trying to split a string at question marks, exclamation marks, or periods, but at the same time I'm trying to keep the punctuation marks after splitting them. How would I do that? Thanks.

```
$input = "Sentence1?Sentence2.Sentence3!";
$input = preg_split("/(\?|\.|!)/", $input);
echo $input[0]."<br>";
echo $input[1]."<br>";
echo $input[2]."<br>";
```

**Desired outputs:**

Sentence1?
Sentence2.
Sentence3!

**Actual outputs:**

Sentence1
Sentence2
Sentence3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by changing the capture group in your regex into a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like so:

```
$input = preg_split("/(?<=\?|\.|!)/", $input);
```

Answer (score 1):

the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) knows all

> PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
>       If this flag is set, parenthesized expression in the delimiter pattern will be captured and returned as well.

so in your case:

```
$input = preg_split("/(\?|\.|!)/", $input,NULL,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: @PaulCrovella I think you're right. When I tested it, an undefined offset error came up, and it only split between sentence1 and sentence2.